# Curl: How can I clear stored data while the program is running

Tags: c, curl, memory, free

I made a text status bar program in C that uses curl to connect to a weather site, grab data, get the correct info, and display it in the bar. That part of the program works perfectly. The issue is that after the program successfully connects to the server, downloads the page, and stores it to memory, and after I extract my weather data and display it, the program doesn't release that memory downloaded, so it takes an extra 15Mb of ram to run until I close the program.

This seems to happen right as I issue:

```
curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

I don't know how to release this memory without closing the program, and I need the program to remain open. I don't want to have to make a separate program and call it, as I would like to use curl in that program for other features (such as pinging the net to check for a connection) in the future, so I might as well just use it while it's there.

I've had this working in C++ perfectly with NO extra memory usage, but I've yet to find the code for C that properly clears the memory.

In order to get to the heart of the situation, I'm going to use code that focuses solely on the issue at hand and that has the exact same issue. It is taken from this website: 
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html

As an aside, I've also tried using this code with no luck. I thought maybe if I just dumped the data, I could at least ping a site and check if my net is up, but it STILL holds that 15Mb of memory:
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html

I've heard of curl leaks, but I cannot truly verify if this is an actual leak or if I am just not releasing the memory properly.

mycurl.c:

```
/*

  Compile with:
  gcc -O2 -Wall mycurl.c -o mycurl -L/usr/include/curl/lib -lcurl

  Courtesy of:
  https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html

*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>  
#include<curl/curl.h>

struct MemoryStruct {
  char *memory;
  size_t size;
};

static size_t
WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
  size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
  struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)userp;

  char *ptr = realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
  if(ptr == NULL) {
    /* out of memory! */ 
    printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
    return 0;
  }

  mem->memory = ptr;
  memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
  mem->size += realsize;
  mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;
  return realsize;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  struct MemoryStruct chunk;

  chunk.memory = malloc(1);
  chunk.size = 0; 

  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  curl = curl_easy_init();

  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");

  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

/* check for errors */ 
  if(res != CURLE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));
    return 1;
  }

  printf("%lu bytes retrieved\n", (unsigned long)chunk.size);

  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  free(chunk.memory);
  curl_global_cleanup();

  /* Everything is all cleaned up, so the memory usage should be back to      normal at this point. */

  printf("Waiting 3 seconds... Watch to see if the memory levels change between now and when the program says 'Done!' If you see a change in memory, there is likely a leak.)\n");


  /* When the program shuts down, the memory is released, but it should release after we cleanup and before the program terminates. Lets give ourselves a few seconds to spot if this is the case. Make sure to have 'top' or 'htop' open and  */

  sleep(3); // top and htop default at 3 second intervals, so we need more than that to spot a change


  printf("\nDone!\nDid the memory change?\n");

  return 0;
}
```

The memory never clears before the program shuts down. I would like to be able to clear that memory and reuse the curl command.

I'm sure you are wondering why am I griping over 15Mb?

The code is to be used for a Raspberry Pi Zero, which is limited to 512Mb ram (cannot be upgraded), and I don't want to give away 15Mb if I really don't have to. Currently, I am running this code on a Raspberry Pi 3B+; though, I've had this issue with curl for a long time, even on other architectures (x86/64).

Would love to get it solved. Thanks. :)

---

**** EDIT ****

---

Credit to hlscalon for his bug reference link and (so far as I can see) finding the cause.

```
apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

The above code, on Debian, will uninstall 'libcurl4-gnutls-dev' and install libcurl4-openssl-dev in its place. This fixed the situation.

Below is a list of sites before and after I switched to libcurl4-openssl-dev. The change in memory consumption went from 15Mb to 1Mb or less on all sites.

To allow other users to easily test if this is perhaps the case for them, I kept all my testing code, which can be quickly cut & pasted and ran:

```
//curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://kernel.org"); // before +15Mb, after +1Mb
  //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://stackoverflow.com"); // before +15Mb, after +1Mb
  //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://blog.apastyle.org/"); // before +15Mb, after +1Mb
  //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://forums.debian.net"); // before +0Mb, after +1Mb
  //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://support.blog.com/create-a-blog/"); // before +0Mb, after +1Mb
  //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://blog.alz.org/"); // before +0Mb, after +0Mb
```

Night and day difference in memory usage. So glad to have this one solved. Thanks again to hlscalon and FredK for their super-hero speed replies and tips.

Consider this post still open to replies pertaining to libcurl4-gnutls-dev being fixed. Sadly, this seems to have been a bug that has been around for a couple of years, so I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: When you call `free()`, there is no guarantee that your OS will actually reduce the size of your footprint. It only guarantees that that memory space it available for your program to re-use; it is operating-system dependent when (or whether) your size will actually be reduced..

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1086) it may not be a problem with curl, possibly with gnutls. If you use http or openssl do you have the same amount of memory allocated ?

Comment: FredK: Strange that C++ would be fine to reduce its size. Good info to know though. Thanks. And, hlscalon, I did a little test (results in original post) and found the results do in deed reflect what you say: there is definitely a difference in memory consumption when visiting an https site compared to an http site. The latter seems to have no issues whatsoever. I read some of that post. I then installed 'libcurl4-openssl-dev' (Debian), which automatically uninstalled 'libcurl4-gnutls-dev', and the problem completely went away for both http and https sites. It is SOLVED! ... for now.